# 403 Forbidden (error code: 50001): Missing Access [discord.py]

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I'm getting this error whenever I try to run my program, I tried giving it all the permissions possible except admin but it still doesn't run, it only runs when I give it admin permission,

the error occurs on on_ready event

here is my code

```py
@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print('------')
    print('Online! Details:')
    print(f"Bot Username: {client.user.name}")
    print(f"BotID: {client.user.id}")
    print('------')
    data = pd.DataFrame(columns=['channel','author'])
    text_channel_list = []
    for i in guild:
      g = client.get_guild(i)
   
      for channel in g.channels:
        if str(channel.type) == 'text':
          text_channel_list.append(channel)
    
    for j in text_channel_list:
      channel = client.get_channel(j.id)
      
      async for msg in channel.history(limit=100000):
        if msg.author != client.user:                                                              
                data = data.append({'channel':msg.channel.name,
                                    'author': msg.author}, ignore_index=True)
        if len(data) == 100000:
            break
        
      file_location = "data.csv"
      data.to_csv(file_location)
    await asyncio.sleep(60)
    client.loop.create_task(on_ready())
```

here is the error

```
------
Online! Details:
Bot Username: Giveaway Bot Dev
BotID: 920320119878602752
------
Ignoring exception in on_ready
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\hires\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 343, in _run_event
    await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "d:\Freelance Giveaway Bot\main.py", line 95, in on_ready
    async for msg in channel.history(limit=100000):
  File "C:\Users\hires\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\discord\iterators.py", line 91, in __anext__
    msg = await self.next()
  File "C:\Users\hires\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\discord\iterators.py", line 285, in next
    await self.fill_messages()
  File "C:\Users\hires\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\discord\iterators.py", line 328, in fill_messages
    data = await self._retrieve_messages(self.retrieve)
  File "C:\Users\hires\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\discord\iterators.py", line 348, in _retrieve_messages_before_strategy
    data = await self.logs_from(self.channel.id, retrieve, before=before)
  File "C:\Users\hires\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\discord\http.py", line 248, in request
    raise Forbidden(r, data)
discord.errors.Forbidden: 403 Forbidden (error code: 50001): Missing Access
```

**EDIT**
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
All these permissions are given already.

Answer (score 1):

I figure out that some on the channel in my server were private and the bot couldn't access them, that's what it was returning a missing access error, I fixed it with a simple try-except

```py
    for j in text_channel_list:
      channel = client.get_channel(j.id)
      try:
        async for msg in channel.history(limit=100000):   
          if msg.author != client.user:                                                              
            data = data.append({'channel':msg.channel.name,
                                'author': msg.author}, ignore_index=True)
          if len(data) == 100000:
              break
      except:
        continue
```

Comment: Maybe accept your answer so others know.

Comment: I can accept my answer after 2 days

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try using a different code? Like so:

```
messages = await channel.history(limit=10000)

for i, message in enumerate(messages):
    message = message.content
    if message.author != client.user:                                                              
        data = data.append({'channel':msg.channel.name,'author': msg.author}, ignore_index=True)
```

Or something like that?

Comment: I have already given it the perms

Comment: Can you take a screenshot and show me?

Comment: @HireshVerma try giving it both read messages and read message history

Comment: I have edited the question

Comment: @HireshVerma oh that's really weird I don't know... 
You might have to use administrator permissions.

Comment: @HireshVerma I edited it maybe now...?

Comment: TypeError: object HistoryIterator can't be used in 'await' expression

Comment: Try taking out the await? Other than this I don't know sorry @HireshVerma

Comment: TypeError: 'HistoryIterator' object is not iterable

Comment: I don't think that there is a problem in the code , It just don't work without admin permission, maybe it is discord's problem idk

Comment: Sorry I don't know anymore, maybe just give the bot administrator permissions @HireshVerma

Comment: yeah , Maybe I have to do that